# Bug? Mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, mat-form-field

it looks like in the new version, le label is not cut when it is too long for the input [image: see the picture]
Please do you know how to fix it ?

I would the like the same behavior as version 12

Comment: You forgot to add the picture. Please update your answer with more information.

Comment: Indeed. I updated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [open bug](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26349) about this on the repo.

Comment: Yes it is the same. Thank you